# Extract spherical region in image at a certain position (with skimage et al.)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

I have (a bunch of 3D) stacks of tomographic data, in those I have deduced a certain (3D) coordinate around which I need to cut out a spherical region.

My code produces me the following image which gives an overview of what I do.
I calculate the orange and green points, based on the dashed white and dashed green region.
Around the midpoint of these, I'd like to cut out a spherical region, the representation of it is now marked with a circle in the image (also drawn by my code).

[image: Screenshot out of my Jupyter notebook]

Constructing a sphere with `skimage.morphology.ball` and multiplying this with the original image is easy to do, but how can I set the center of the sphere at the desired 3D location in the image?
The ~30 3D stacks of images are all of different size with different regions, but I have all the necessary coordinates ready for further use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0. you have some radius `r` and an index `(i,j,k)` into the data.
1. `kernel = skimage.morphology.ball(r)` returns a mask/kernel which is `a = 2*r + 1` along each side. It's cube-shaped.
2. Take a cube-shaped slice, the size of your kernel, out of the tomograph. Starting indices depend on where you need the center to be and what radius the kernel has.

   `piece = data[i-r:i-r+a, j-r:j-r+a, k-r:k-r+a]`
3. Apply the binary "ball" mask/kernel to the slice.

   `piece *= kernel`

Comment: Thanks for the input! I (think I) *need* to keep the extent of the original image to make subsequent masking/calculations easier. But this simply means I have to 'slice' in the kernel into an empty numpy array first and then multiply this with the original data.

Comment: you could use `np.mgrid[]` (yes, it takes slices) to build and around an array of indices. that's convenient if you need to transform them in some way. depends on what exactly you're planning to do though.

Comment: BTW: The image is not a tree trunk, something *much* smaller; contrast-agent instilled rat hearts with 'something' on top. Not ready to talk about it in more detail, but hope that this gives a publication soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches that I use that show two approaches to 'operating' (calculating values in some way) for  sub-regions within an array.  The two different approaches are:

*So say you wanted to calculate the mean of only the values in your spherical region:*

1 - **Specify coordinates of the region directly as a 'slice'**:
`data[region_coordinates].mean()`

2 - **Use a masked version of your array**, where the mask is used to specify the region: `data_masked.mean()`

Which might be better depends on what you may want to do with the values in the region.  Both can be used inter-changebly, you can just choose which makes your code clearer/easier/faster.

---

In my work, I use both approaches, but more commonly the first approach (where you specify a region as a 'slice' of coordinates).

For me, the coordinate slice approach has advantages:

1 - It's more explicitly obvious what is going on

2 - You can more easily apply geometric operations to your 'region' if you need to. (e.g. rotate, translate, scale, ...)

Here is example code, and methods you can use for either approach:

```py
mport numpy as np
import skimage.morphology as mo
from typing import Tuple


def get_ball_coords(radius: int, center: Tuple[int]) -> Tuple[np.ndarray]:
    """
    Use radius and center to return the coordinates within that 3d region
    as a 'slice'.
    """

    coords = np.nonzero(mo.ball(radius))
    # 'coords' is a tuple of 1d arrays - to move center using pure numpy, 
    # first convert to a 2d array
    coords_array = np.array(coords)
    center_array = np.array([center]).T

    # transform coordinates to be centered at 'center'
    coords_array = coords_array - radius + center_array
    # convert coordinates back to tuple of 1d arrays, which can be used
    # directly as a slice specification
    coords_tuple = (
        coords_array[0,:],
        coords_array[1,:],
        coords_array[2,:]
    )

    return coords_tuple


def get_masked_array(data: np.ndarray, radius: int, center: Tuple[int]) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Return a masked version of the data array, where all values are masked
    except for the values within the sphere specified by radius and center.
    """

    # get 'ball' as 2d array of booleans
    ball = np.array(mo.ball(radius), dtype=bool)
    # create full mask over entire data array
    mask = np.full_like(data, True, dtype=bool)
    # un-mask the 'ball' region, translated to the 'center'
    mask[
        center[0]-radius: center[0]+radius+1,
        center[1]-radius: center[1]+radius+1,
        center[2]-radius: center[2]+radius+1
    ] = ~ball
    # mask is now True everywhere, except inside the 'ball'
    # at 'center' - create masked array version of data using this.
    masked_data = np.ma.array(data=data, mask=mask)
    return masked_data



# make some 3D data
data_size = (100,100,100)
data = np.random.rand(*data_size)


# define some spherical region by radius and center
region_radius = 2
region_center = (23, 41, 53)

# get coordinates of this region
region_coords = get_ball_coords(region_radius, region_center)

# get masked version of the data, based on this region
data_masked = get_masked_array(data, region_radius, region_center)

# now you can use 'region_coords' as a single 'index' (slice)
# to specify only the points with those coordinates
print('\nUSING COORDINATES:')
print('here is mean value in the region:')
print(data[region_coords].mean())
print('here is the total data mean:')
print(data.mean())

# of you can use the masked array as-is:
print('\nUSING MASKED DATA:')
print('here is mean value in the region:')
print(data_masked.mean())
print('here is the total data mean:')
print(data.mean())
```

Comment: Thanks for the great input @Richard. The masked array is an especially good idea. Since I'm saving out the cutout-images to disk anyway (for faster processing when the pipeline is re-run) I calculate the necessary information from the region in a further step, but in a way suggested by you.

Comment: Welcome - these are the two approaches I know.  But there are likely others (with numpy I'm always coming across new ways of doing things), so researching and reading some more is probably a good way to go.